# laptop has two video cards - unable to tell it to use intel one

Tags: ubuntu, linux-mint, nvidia-graphics-card, nvidia-geforce, asus-laptop

I type in `lspci | grep VGA` in bash and get the following back:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Mobile 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 07)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation G98M [GeForce G 105M] (rev a1)
```

The fact that I have two video controllers is surprising. [Nvidia Optimus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nvidia_Optimus) cards have two video controllers but the GeForce G 105M isn't an Nvidia Optimus card:

http://www.geforce.com/hardware/notebook-gpus/geforce-g105m

(in contrast http://www.geforce.com/hardware/notebook-gpus/geforce-gtx-980m mentions both Optimus and CUDA in the GeForce Technologies section)

Regardless, I tried to do `sudo prime-select intel` to make the laptop use the intel video card and here's what I got:

```
Info: the current GL alternatives in use are: ['mesa', 'mesa']
Info: the current EGL alternatives in use are: ['mesa-egl', None]
Error: the installed packages do not support PRIME
Error: intel mode can't be enabled
```

That was with the `xserver-xorg-video-nouveau` driver.

I also tried to do the steps at https://johners.tech/2016/06/nvidia-optimus-on-linux-mint-18/ with the `nvidia-340` driver but I don't see `PRIME Profiles` as an option in the left hand menu:

[image]

Any ideas?